# Database table with single field

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, persistence, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Lightswitch project written in C# with Silverlight. I've been thinking and looking for a professionnal way to deal with single entities/objects that must be modifiable by users, and having those changes be reflected for every other user. Those entities don't belong to any table because they don't share similar fields, and obviously I wouldn't want to create a table for each one of them (about 10-20).

An example would be a multiplying factor for some specific pricing. That factor must be the same for every user, but the users must be able to change it after some time because pricing structure changes.

What would be an efficient way to deal with those ?

---

More info on the project:

Users will want to be able to go to a specific screen, change the value of the entity in a `textbox` for example (could be any other UI element though), and then some other entities would use that new value for their computed properties.

Comment: A single table with a column for every variable. A configuration file. A table with a single column storing a BLOB with said configuration data. It kind of depends on where and how you want to use that multiplying factor. Also the kind of application would matter and how users interact with it.

Comment: @Seth Hmm, I'll try to provide more info, but I'm not really sure what details matter most.

Comment: I''m not familiar with lightswitch so I might be missing some information there. But as an example is it a standalone application or browser based? Does it have a centralized server (aside from the DB)? The real target would be to figure out at which locations configuration information could be stored. Having a config on each client is way different form a centralized configuration file. From the information you have supplied (if I wanted to keep it in the DB) I would probably opt for 1 table with N columns. This might have issue though with locking etc.

Comment: It's an out-of-browser, desktop app. Deployed on a SQL Server, 3-tier.